# Google Api GameService No individual errors - .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I´m trying to use GameService API to list a game AchievementDefinitions, but always return [500] No individual errors. I´m using ServiceAccountCredential to authenticate.

I tried two ways to auth

```
string credPath = @"C:\Downloads\game-bd201016b65f.json";
var json = File.ReadAllText(credPath);
var cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

var xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.client_email.ToString())
{
    Scopes = new[] { GamesService.Scope.Games }
}.FromPrivateKey(cr.private_key.ToString()));

var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = xCred               
};

GamesService gamesService = new GamesService(initializer);
var a = gamesService.AchievementDefinitions.List().Execute();
```

and

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\game-bd201016b65f.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
}

if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
{
    credential = credential.CreateScoped(GamesService.Scope.Games);
}

var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential              
};
```

Can be an API error when running in .NET?

Comment: Can you post the full error message.  How do you know that that api supports service accounts were you able to pre-authorize it?

Comment: Thanks for reply @DaImTo. GameService is used just to get user information. To get the game information need to use GameService Managment API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameService API is used to get user authenticated information and what i need is get the Game information, to get the game information need to use GameService Management API.
Using GameService Management API i can auth with ServiceAccountCredential and get the game information.